# Add border to jquery draggable element on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

From jquery ui draggable internally it fires blur event so I am unable to set border to the container. Is there anything I am missing? How can I set border on select of the draggable element. I am trying to add border on select(on mouse down).

```js
$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#draggable").on('focus', function() {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid')
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).css('border', '')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" tabIndex = -1>
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dragstart` and `dragstop` events. Here is the reference for documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event

```
$("#draggable").on('dragstart', function() {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid')
}).on("dragstop",function() {
  $(this).css('border', '0')
});
```

Use `mousedown` to add border before dragging starts

```
$("#draggable").on('mousedown', function() {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid')
}).on("dragstop",function() {
  $(this).css('border', '0')
});
```

Comment: It will fire on drag only, on select I need to add border.

Comment: @Escoute I edited my answer to accommodate "on select" in other words "mousedown"

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the class added when dragging `.ui-draggable-dragging` or add your own class using the start and stop events.

```js
$("#draggable").draggable({
  start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.addClass('active');
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.ui-draggable-dragging {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.active {
  outline: 3px dashed yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
```

Comment: It is adding on drag start, on select I need to add border.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a new css class that specifies what it should look like when active:

```
#draggable:active {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this won't work. Because from jquery ui, it fires blur event on mouse down. So focus won't be there in that element.